# TensorFlow in iOS Swift:Binary classification problem

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow-lite

I am having some issues while getting output in TensorFlow Model(tflite).

This is my input:

```
 let inputInfo:[Float32]  : [-1.0291401 ,  1.6121695 ,  0.58366895, -0.25974554,  2.6633718 ,
                                  0.39398468,  1.2648116 , -1.0617405 ,  1.0997621 , -0.01813432,
                                 -0.02543107,  1.9113901 ,  0.30188444,  0.3199759 ,  0.07759953,
                                  0.23082322,  2.0959156 , -0.42658705,  0.08775132,  3.4258583 ,
                                 -1.0573974 ,  0.7249298 , -1.1119401 , -0.72663903, -0.74873704,
                                 -0.387724  , -0.14288527, -0.39554232, -0.10774904, -0.0911286 ,
                                  0.40389383, -0.169619  , -1.1736624 ]

 let inputData = Data(bytes: &inputInfo, count: inputInfo.count * MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride)
 print(inputData)
 try interpreter?.copy(inputData, toInputAt: 0)
```

After passing this array of Float32 type as input I am getting below result in output:

Output:

TensorFlowLite.Tensor(name: "Identity", dataType: TensorFlowLite.Tensor.DataType.float32, shape: TensorFlowLite.Tensor.Shape(rank: 2, dimensions: [1, 1]), data: 4 bytes, quantizationParameters: nil)

For getting the expexcted output result I am using this code:

```
let outputTensor = try self.interpreter?.output(at: 0)
let finalOutput = [Float32](unsafeData: outputTensor!.data)
 print(finalOutput)
 4.6533377e+33
```

Here expected output should be some numbers between 0 & 1(like 0.8,0.9) but my final output is beyond that expected output.
I am stuck here,please help.